# Audio File Duration Using JAVA

Tags: java, audio

I am using following code to find duration of audio file

```
 MpegAudioFileReader reader = new MpegAudioFileReader();
            AudioFileFormat aff = reader.getAudioFileFormat(file);
            Map<String, Object> propMap = aff.properties();
            System.out.println(propMap);
            Object obj = propMap.get("duration");
            System.out.println("duration:::" +propMap.get("duration"));
```

But in one case i get 20minute and 57seconds for a particular audio but its playing 41 minutes .

What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide some link to said file? I've tried using your code for few of my mp3 files and everything worked fine.

Comment: That audio file in my system .how i upload that audio?